# When I tried build the my solution I am getting build errors and I already added those dll's in my project also

Tags: asp.net-4.8

Compile time build errors

> Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.UltraGridExcelExporter, Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.1010, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException    Uniprise.UGAF.Presentation.Fee  ..\Presentation\Fee\licenses.licx   1

> Error      Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid, Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.1010, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException  Uniprise.UGAF.Presentation.Fee  ...\Presentation\Fee\licenses.licx  2

need to resolve build errors ,we have added those dll's

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update or configure the license file for the Infragistics components in your project.

More info about this can be found in the [Windows Forms Help section](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/introduction-tips-for-installing-infragistics-windows-forms) of the Infragistics website.